# Override an existing defined constant

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you assign values to constants with equal sign after using defined in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931716/can-you-assign-values-to-constants-with-equal-sign-after-using-defined-in-php)

I'm not sure if it's just me, but how do you override an existing constant something like this:

```
define('HELLO', 'goodbye');
define('HELLO', 'hello!');

echo HELLO; <-- I need it to output "hello!"

//unset(HELLO); <-- unset doesn't work
//define('HELLO', 'hello!');
```

Comment: The points raised here are pedantic - I have to work in a 7 year old system, which is massive, and duplicated across multiple servers for hundreds of clients. This isn't my creation, but I have to work with it. ONE customer wants just ONE bit of customization, which requires changing a defined constant. So, by the arguments raised above, I have gut an entire system, affecting my 100+ co-workers, just so I can be "correct" for exactly ONE client. Yeah, maybe instead of blurting pedantic drivel, just answer the question, yes or no.

Comment: Nathan, I feel your pain. I too wish SO has less preaching and more correct answers - some of us work in the real world.

Comment: If you don't mind a PHP Notice, it may work for some situations to add your custom define() BEFORE the standard one. That will "override" it in the sense that the standard define will report an error and won't take since it happens afterward.

Answer (score 11):

You can override a constant if it extended from a class.
So in your case you can't override constant as it consider came from a same class.
ie ([taken from php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#102199)):

```
<?php

class Foo {
    const a = 7;
    const x = 99;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    const a = 42; /* overrides the `a = 7' in base class */
}

$b = new Bar();
$r = new ReflectionObject($b);
echo $r->getConstant('a');  # prints `42' from the Bar class
echo "\n";
echo $r->getConstant('x');  # prints `99' inherited from the Foo class

?>
```

If you turn on php error reporting 
ie:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

you will see a notice like

```
Notice: Constant HELLO already defined in ....
```

Answer (score 11):

Truth is, you can, but you should not.
PHP being an interpreted language, there is nothing you "can't" do.
The runkit extension allow you to modify PHP internals behavior, and provide the runkit_constant_redefine(simple signature) function.

Answer (score 7):

If the page is reloading, you can have a dynamic value change the constant.

Like:

```
$random = something_that_gives_me_randomness();

define('HELLO', $random);
```

But if you are trying to change a constant in the same script, then linepogl is correct. Its called a constant for a reason.