# Can you assign values to constants with equal sign after using defined in php?

Tags: php, constants

I know to define a constant, you do something like this

```
define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");
```

if I want to change the value of the constant I would have to do define() again? Why couldn't I just do `CONSTANT = "whatever";` after it has already been defined the first time?

Comment: [CONSTANT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The whole point of a constant is that it is constantly and always the same. You can not change a constant after you defined it.

Even using `define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");` would return an error.

I just did it real fast to show you what you'd get:

```
Notice: Constant CONSTANT already defined in /Users/stokholm/test.php on line 3

Call Stack:
    0.0003     629992   1. {main}() /Users/stokholm/test.php:0
    0.0171     630232   2. define() /Users/stokholm/test.php:3
```

Comment: My whole situation is the constant is defined in a while I can not change but I do need to change its value, it's unfortunate that I can't

Comment: In that case you should use a variable. Constants is for things that will not change at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Constants, as the name specifies, cannot be changed once defined.  Use variables instead.